# Firefox "Unable to connect" without www?

Tags: firefox, browser, nginx, cross-browser

I wasn't sure whether to put this in Serverfault or on Stackoverflow; it doesn't seem to be a server issue so I though here would be best.

I am currently working on a university website, and for some reason Firefox refuses to load the site unless you use www (ex www.university.edu). Every other browser accepts university.edu and simply redirects to www.university.edu as nginx is setup to do. My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name university.edu www;
    rewritei    ^http://www.university.edu$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.university.edu static.university.edu m.university.edu www.university.com;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So what should happen is when a request comes in and is www.university.edu, the second block catches it and everything runs normally, but if a request comes in and is university.edu the first block catches it and redirects it to the second block. But for some reason Firefox is not doing this.

Any idea's what could be causing this issue?

**Update 1:**
rewritei is not mispelled. The university's nginx was changed before it was compiled to enable regex case insensitivity, and was placed under the function "rewritei". Also after playing around with the site I found figured out that if you visit the site at www.university.edu first, then try university.edu it will load, but if you clear the cache and try to visit university.edu it will not load until you visit www.university.edu.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo; "rewrite" and try removing the www.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name university.edu;
    return 301 http://www.university.edu$request_uri;
}
```

Also take a look at the pitfalls on rewrite - http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites

Comment: Actually I compiled nginx with a regex insensitive rewrite capability and named it rewritei so that is correct. Secondly the www is an on campus shortcut to the website (so jus typing in www will take you to www.university.edu) and has to stay as well.

As for the "return 301 ...", that unfortunately did not help either.

Comment: Did the access get captured in the logs? And what about the Firefox HTTP response headers? Does it show redirect or unable to connect?

Comment: The access logs will not help, in the few seconds it takes for me to back up, clear them, and refresh the broswer page, the logs have 800 requests (it's a busy site).

As for Firefox's response header; FF sends a GET request to http://university.edu, but the response panel is just blank.